# Proof that $S_3$ is the smallest non-commutative group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Before I start attempting to show that every group of order less than 6 is commutative, is there a shorter/faster way to go about proving this?

Comment: Well, every group of prime order is commutative

Comment: If the order of a group is prime then the group is cyclic hence commutative. So only groups with order $4$ need attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

order of $S_3$ is 6 so brute force is not bad...infact i don't know of any other method apart from the fact that all the orders below 6 are either prime or of the form $p^2$ and hence abelian but these are $big$ theorems which are being used for problems that have easier alternative solution..